# Grails Services / Transactions / RuntimeException / Testing

Tags: grails, transactions, rollback, runtimeexception

I'm testing come code in a service with transactional set to true , which talks 
to a customer supplied web service the main part of which looks like

```
class BarcodeService { 
..  
/// some stuff  ...  

try{
      cancelBarCodeResponse = cancelBarCode(cancelBarcodeRequest)
} catch(myCommsException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException(e)
}
...
```

where myCommsException  extends Exception  ..

I have a test which looks like

```
// As no connection from my machine, it should fail ..

shouldFailWithCause(RuntimeException){
  barcodeServices.cancelBarcodeDetails()
}
```

The test fails cause it's catching a myCommsException rather than the 
RuntimeException i thought i'd converted it to .. Anyone care to point out what 
i'm doing wrong  ? Also will the fact that it's not a RuntimeException mean any 
transaction related info done before my try/catch actually be written out rather 
than thrown away  ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, it looks ok.  The problem might be in the ///some stuff and the ... parts of the code.  Use a debugger to find out exactly where the exception is being thrown.